# No Device Node in device tree for Pin Controller of HiFive Unleashed

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, riscv, device-tree

I am trying to interface Wiznet w5500 module (SPI to Ethernet module) with HiFive Unleashed running Linux image generated through Freedom-U-SDK. I have integrated the wiznet driver into my Linux image. And I also know that I have to update my device tree in order to let the driver work for w5500 hardware. While reading device tree binding of wiznet module ([Link](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/plain/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/net/wiznet,w5x00.txt)), I came to know that I have to enter pinctrl-0 entry in my device tree node for wiznet module.

While investigating device tree includes of HiFive Unleashed, I couldn’t find any pin controller node for the hardware ([Link](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/arch/riscv/boot/dts/sifive?h=linux-5.8.y)) to whom I can reference and add my pins into.

I have added this patch in device tree for representing wiznet w5500 module:

```auto
arch/riscv/boot/dts/sifive/hifive-unleashed-a00.dts | 13 +++++++++++++
 1 file changed, 13 insertions(+)

diff --git a/arch/riscv/boot/dts/sifive/hifive-unleashed-a00.dts b/arch/riscv/boot/dts/sifive/hifive-unleashed-a00.dts
index 4a2729f5ca3f..b0d000cfc82a 100644
--- a/arch/riscv/boot/dts/sifive/hifive-unleashed-a00.dts
+++ b/arch/riscv/boot/dts/sifive/hifive-unleashed-a00.dts
@@ -72,6 +72,19 @@
    };
 };
 
+&qspi1 {
+   status = "okay";
+   w5500: ethernet@0 {
+       compatible = "wiznet,w5500";
+       pinctrl-names = "default";
+       pinctrl-0 = <&gpio>;
+       reg = <0x0>;
+       interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
+       interrupts = <16>;
+       spi-max-frequency = <10000000>;
+   };
+};
+
 &qspi2 {
    status = "okay";
    mmc@0 {
--
```

But no device appears in */dev* directory corresponding to wiznet module.

Please help me adding pins for my wiznet module, is there something I am missing?

Comment: QSPI is usual interface for NAND chips. Are you sure you are using proper SPI controller?

Comment: Sorry for late reply and thanks for the pointer. But I'm pretty new with embedded software development. How to identify if this peripheral is SPI or QSPI that can be used with flash memories only?
I've seen the Technical Reference Manual of my board, there is a chapter on SPI that only lists resigter map of the peripheral. And lists the 3 QSPI devices. On other QSPI devices a uSD Card jack and ISSI QSPI Flash memory are attached. Are these pointers that I cannot used QSPI as an SPI peripheral?